# How to use knockoutjs with a dropdown from server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

from server I get either an A or a B or a G for type

What I want it to show is a drop down of a text Gamma if it is G and Alpha if it is A and Beta if it is B. Also that item to be selected ... Not sure how to do this.

Here is what I get from my back end.. an observable array of

```
  self.AllValues = ko.observableArray([{"ID":1,"Type":"A" .... }]);
```

I have something like below the type is A B OR G ...

```
 <td class="label">Drop-down list:</td>
 <td><select data-bind="options: optionValues, value: selectedOptionValue"></select>
 </td>
```

Comment: Are you saying that you don't get the text Alpha, Beta and Gamma back from the server?

Comment: Correct I don't. only A B or G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of choices here. You can either process the data that you get back from the server, and add a property containing the full text name to each object, and then bind your array to the select, using this new property for the text of the select, or else you can use [Custom Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) to create the select element and all the options in it, substituting the full text that you want in each option.

I'd say that the first option would be the nicest one to implement.

Comment: How about handling it with checkboxes instead?

Comment: Instead of a Select? Not sure I understand, even after looking at the jsFiddle! In your fiddle, you'd need to set the value to A, B, G, rather than the full name.